How do I replace the version of assembly c# a visual studio project uses with a specific file?
I'm following a tutorial that requires me to use STRIPPED-Assembly-CSharp instead of PUBLIC-Assembly-CSharp. The tutorial said to replace the PUBLIC-Assembly-CSharp in the "lib" folder with STRIPPED-Assembly-CSharp, but I can't find that folder. The tutorial has provided the dll file for STRIPPED-Assembly-CSharp, I just need to find out how to use it instead of PUBLIC-Assembly-CSharp. The tutorial project and my project are both C# libraries exported as a dll.
I googled how to switch the version of Assembly-CSharp a project uses, but it only gave me answers on how to switch to an earlier version of PUBLIC-Assembly-CSharp. I checked the project settings, but there was no option to switch the assembly file. Visual Studio's search bar also yielded no results. Next, I tried to replace the PUBLIC-Assembly-CSharp files in the release and debug bin. This had no effect on how the project was built. After that, I searched my entire pc for files named PUBLIC-Assembly-CSharp to see if I could find the file I was supposed to replace. Unfortunately, all of the PUBLIC-Assembly-CSharp files were in a project's release or debug bin. I also unloaded my csproj file, opened the project's xml code, and used control f to find all instances of PUBLIC-Assembly-CSharp incase I could change it manually. There were no mentions of it in the file. Finally, I switched my project's version of c# so it matched the one used in the tutorial(The network version already matched the tutorial.) And updated my version of visual studio so it matched the latest release. None of the changes caused the lib folder or an option to change the assembly file to appear.

Nevermind, I found out how to switch it. I needed to replace the "PUBLIC-Assembly-CSharp" reference with the file I wanted to replace it with.

@Duskkite: if you think that it might help other people feel free to answer your own question and accept it. But then provide more information.

Glad to know your problem has been solved! See Can I answer my own question?  Just a reminder :)
